# shift y-axis from dumbell chart within the line

Tags: highcharts

I want to shift the y-axis as in dumbell Highchart:
refer images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBSHP.png
Please help me on that part

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust labels position by using `align` and `x` properties:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 0
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vbrjqc2w/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels